# Linux Sniffer Between Client and Server Libpcap

Tags: linux, libpcap, sniffer

I am trying to create a sniffer which reads a text being sent from server to client using inet address 127.0.0.1 (loopback address). Program keeps stays halts even when client has received data from server.

CODE of sniffer :

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{ 
    char *dev; 
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t* descr;
    bpf_u_int32 maskp;          /* subnet mask               */
    bpf_u_int32 netp;           /* ip*/
    struct bpf_program fp;      /* hold compiled program            */
    char *filter = "host 127.0.0.1";
    //char *filter = "port 5000";

    dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
    if(dev == NULL)
    { printf("%s\n",errbuf); exit(1); }
                printf("call success");

    /* ask pcap for the network address and mask of the device */
    pcap_lookupnet(dev,&netp,&maskp,errbuf);

    descr = pcap_open_live(dev,BUFSIZ,1,-1,errbuf);
    if(descr == NULL)
    { printf("pcap_open_live(): %s\n",errbuf); exit(1); }

                    /* Lets try and compile the program.. non-optimized */
    if(pcap_compile(descr,&fp,filter,0,netp) == -1)
    { fprintf(stderr,"Error calling pcap_compile\n"); exit(1); }

    /* set the compiled program as the filter */
    if(pcap_setfilter(descr,&fp) == -1)
    { fprintf(stderr,"Error setting filter\n"); exit(1); }


    pcap_loop(descr,2,callback,NULL);

    fprintf(stdout,"\nfinished\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Server and client are using port 5000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing -1 as the *to_ms* argument to `pcap_open_live()`.  The behavior for a negative timeout is undefined; you should specify a *positive* value.  The value is in units of milliseconds; tcpdump uses 1000, i.e. 1 second, whereas Wireshark uses 250, i.e. 1/4 second.

You're also capturing on the default device, as you're using `pcap_lookupdev()`.  That is rarely, if ever, the loopback device, so if you capture on the default device, you will rarely, if ever, see *any* traffic if you use the filter `host 127.0.0.1`.  If the server and client are *both* running on the same machine as the machine on which you're running your program, you need to capture on the loopback device, which is named `"lo"` on Linux.  If the server and client are *not* both running on the same machine, then your traffic will *not* use address 127.0.0.1, and you will need to pick a different address.

Comment: Thankyou. I will see that. But is the method to use filter for loopback address "char filter="127.0.0.1""  correct?

Comment: Or do i need to filter by port 5000?